# Determine the distribution for a number list

Tags: statistics, distribution

I have a list of numbers. Below are some basic statistics:

```
N > 1000
Max: 9.24
Min: 0.00955
Mean: 1.84932
Median: 0.97696
```

It seems that the data is right skewed, i.e. many small numbers and a few very large numbers.

I want to find a distribution to generalize these numbers. I think Normal distribution, Gamma distribution, and Laplace distribution all look possible. How do I determine which distribution is the best?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics rather than programming.  It might be a better fit on stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that I usually do it in the same way you did it, by plotting the data I seeing its shape. 
When being more accurate, and only for the normal distribution, I perform the Shapiro Wilk test for normality, which at least will tell me that the null hypotesis was not proven, which means that it was not possible to prove that the date does not follow a normal distribution. Usually, this is more than acceptable in scientific environments.

I know there exists equivalent tests for Laplace and Gamma distributions, although still in newly research like [this](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949650903520936#preview). Instead, there are many sites that offer the Shapiro Wilk test online, like this [one](http://sdittami.altervista.org/shapirotest/ShapiroTest.html).

Answer (score 0):

With all positive values and the mean being about double the median, your data are definitely skewed right. You can rule out both normal and Laplace because both are symmetric and can go negative.

Scope out some of the many fine alternatives at the [Wikipedia distributions page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_semi-infinite_intervals.2C_usually_.5B0.2C.E2.88.9E.29). Make a histogram of your data and check it for similarities in shape to those distributions.  Exponentials, log normals, chi-squares, and the gamma family could all give numeric results such as the ones you described, but without knowing anything about the variance/std deviation, whether your data are unimodal or multimodal, or where the mode(s) are, we can only make guesses about a very large pool of possibilities.